DC-DC converter step-up double stage cascade
i made a cascade dc converter using mc34063 but using an external transistor, my main goal is to charge the capacitor at the 2200uf output in about 5-8 seconds, the input voltage is 3.7 ideally when the voltage is 6-7V for this I used two step up circuits first increased to 10V and then I need to get 80V but when I connect the second dc converter, the voltage at the output where it should be 10V drops to 3, the problem is how can I organize a cascade amplification circuit and what could be my problem?



Above image was taken from: MC34063 HV boost on Multisim by user macbum



Above image of Double cascaded DC-DC boost converter circuit was taken from this paper on ResearchGate:
Balci, S., Kayabasi, A., & Yildiz, B. (2019). "ANN-based estimation of the voltage ripple according to the load variation of battery chargers." International Journal of Electronics, 107(1), 17–27. https://doi.org/10.1080/00207217.2019.1591530

Tural Heydarov - Hi, Thanks for adding links to the sources of the copied schematics. I improved those references. I was going to try to improve the readability of the text, but some parts are unclear to me e.g. input voltage is 3.7V, but then why mention 6-7V? || Also, it's clear that your actual schematic is not either of the ones you included, since the Multisim schematic is only single-stage & the one from the research paper is incomplete. Can you please add your actual schematic & BOM showing all component values? Also add a photo of your prototype, in case site members see an issue. TY

Yes, you are right, I used this circuit from the multisim and added one more cascade of the same type to it, I will certainly send my circuit.

Congratulations on successfully resolving your issue! Could you please contribute to this community by adding a section to describe your solution following your question? Including schematic diagrams (Multisim would be ideal for sharing simulations) would be very helpful. I'm confident it will assist others facing similar challenges. Additionally, please kindly update your question as requested by SamGibson. Thank you for being a responsible and helpful https://electronics.stackexchange.com  contributor.

For computing the appropriate values for the components for the MC34063, use this calculator. Here is an example based on your requirements using single stage rather than cascaded one.


thanks for calculator , i have a problem , i need to charge output capacitor anout 5-8 sec upto 80v when volatge starts from 3.7 it takes about 20 sec , bit if it will start from 10v it will charge about 5-8 sec , so i chose cascade with external transistor first i get 10v and then 80 but there is this problem that it drops to 3v when i connect another dc converted

Charging a 2200µF capacitor to 80V within 8 seconds requires a peak current in the order of 10A. The MC34063 would not be suitable for such a requirement. I am not surprised that the first stage could not sustain 10V because the first stage was not capable of delivering enough current for the second stage using MC34063.

I understand, thank you very much, so even if I use external NMOS, this will not solve the problem?

You probably could. But you must ensure that (1) The external NMOS is capable of handling several times the peak current. (2) The inductor is rated for the peak current. (3) Choose appropriate size for R3 to ensure that the NMOS can turn off fast enough to not heat up. I suggest single stage rather than multi-stage.

(4) Feed high enough voltage to Vcc of MC34063 preferably >10V, so that it can drive the external NMOS with appropriate voltage.

thank you very much for the advice, yes, indeed at >10 volts the capacitor charges within 2 seconds
